# Random Horizontal Scrollbar on Website

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

A new client has come to me with a strange issue they've got on their website, for some reason it's displaying a horizontal scrollbar, and I'm really not sure how to get rid of it.

Help is appreciated.

http://www.hearthstoneresort.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this width setting under `div#tagline p` from Hearthstone.css

```
div#tagline p
{
width: 828px; // remove this because it's positioned absolutely.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the body width to 100% instead of 828px in the css file.
Or a hack like :

```
overflow:hidden;
```

in css always work.

Answer (score 0):

add in stylesheet under body tag 'overflow-x: hidden;'

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```